# How to run Cassandra Hector client example?

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

I have got simple example with Hector library for Cassandra: https://github.com/zznate/cassandra-tutorial/tree/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/tutorial
Compilation went succesfully.
But I can't run it:

```
        root@ns38:/home/marcin/work/java/jctserv/hector-core-1.0-3# javac -cp cassandra-thrift-1.0.6.jar:FastInfoset-1.2.2.jar:slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:uuid-3.2.0.jar:commons-lang-2.4.jar:guava-r09.jar:speed4j-0.9.jar:commons-pool-1.5.3.jar:hector-core-1.0-3.jar InsertRowsForColumnFamilies.java TutorialCommand.java
root@ns38:/home/marcin/work/java/jctserv/hector-core-1.0-3# java InsertRowsForColumnFamilies
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: InsertRowsForColumnFamilies (wrong name: com/datastax/tutorial/InsertRowsForColumnFamilies)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: InsertRowsForColumnFamilies.  Program will exit.
root@ns38:/home/marcin/work/java/jctserv/hector-core-1.0-3#
```

What I do wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Try this. java com.datastax.tutorial.InsertRowsForColumnFamilies

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the class file in the appropriate folder as per package mentioned then call Java with classpath and fully qualified class name. See http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/course/601/lectures/java.tools.html

try:

```
java -cp cassandra-thrift-1.0.6.jar:FastInfoset-1.2.2.jar:slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:uuid-3.2.0.jar:commons-lang-2.4.jar:guava-r09.jar:speed4j-0.9.jar:commons-pool-1.5.3.jar:hector-core-1.0-3.jar com.datastax.tutorial.InsertRowsForColumnFamilies
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
java com.datastax.tutorial.InsertRowsForColumnFamilies
```